# Testing i18next with Jest results in t is not a function error

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, ts-jest, i18next, react-i18next

I have the following helper function for translating parts of my codebase where I'm using i18next outside of React components (React components use the `useTranslation` hook):

```js
// localizeMessage.ts
import i18nInstance, { locale } from "i18n/index";

export default (localizationKey: string, options?: Record<string, unknown>): string => {
  return i18nInstance.t(localizationKey, {
    lng: locale || "en",
    ...options,
  });
};
```

I'm trying to add a simple unit test, where instead of using the imported i18nInstance (which uses a backend to load translation files and gets `locale` from the browser), I want to use this test instance:

```js
// i18nForTests.ts

import { createInstance } from "i18next";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";
import strings_en from "src/i18n/locales/en.json";

const i18nInstance = createInstance();

void i18nInstance.use(initReactI18next).init({
  lng: "en",
  fallbackLng: "en",
  resources: {
    en: {
      translation: strings_en,
    },
  },
  debug: true,
  interpolation: {
    escapeValue: false,
  },
});

export default i18nInstance;
```

This is my test:

```js
// localizeMessage.test.ts
import localizeMessage from "store/utils/localizeMessage";
import i18nInstance from "test/utils/i18nForTests";

jest.mock("i18n/index", () => ({
  i18nInstance: () => i18nInstance,
  locale: "en",
}));

describe("localizeMessage", () => {
  test("returns the correct localized string", () => {
    const result = localizeMessage(
      "path.to.real.message"
    );

    expect(result).toEqual(
      "This is a real message."
    );
  });

  test("returns the correct localized string with options", () => {
    const result = localizeMessage(
      "path.to.real.message.with.options",
      { count: "42" }
    );

    expect(result).toEqual(
      "The answer to life, the universe, and everything is 42."
    );
  });
});
```

When I run it, I get the error `TypeError: index_1.default.t is not a function`. What am I doing wrong?